# Find available data in an ManagementObject

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I'm using ManagementObjectSearcher to load all the printers available in the network. There all the printers are returned in a ManagementObjectCollection. Is there anyway to find out all the details returned?

I used the debugging of c# to preview the object but it does not show all the data in there. I want to know what is available other than Printers[Name],Printers[Local],Printers[Network]. Is there a possible way to do this?

**Code**

```
System.Management.ManagementScope objMS =
            new System.Management.ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
        objMS.Connect();

        SelectQuery objQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
        ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objMS, objQuery);
        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMOS.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject Printers in objMOC)
        {
            System.Management.PropertyDataCollection pdc = Printers.Properties;
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Printers["Local"]))       // LOCAL PRINTERS.
            {
                comboBox8.Items.Add(Printers["Name"]);
            }
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Printers["Network"]))     // ALL NETWORK PRINTERS.
            {
                comboBox9.Items.Add(Printers["Name"]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate strongly typed classes for Win32_Printer that will show you everything you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wkebaxa(v=vs.110).aspx - Mgmtclassgen.exe (Management Strongly Typed Class Generator)

Comment: Hey mate.

I am finding an error **Type 'logicalDisk' is not defined** because I can't use `Imports ROOT.CIMV2.Win32 `. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the `ManagementBaseObject.Properties` property, and `PropertyData.Qualifiers`.

```
    foreach (PropertyData property in properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name);

        foreach (QualifierData q in property.Qualifiers)
        {
            if(q.Name.Equals("Description"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    processClass.GetPropertyQualifierValue(
                    property.Name, q.Name));
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.properties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)